# Post and pre increment

Tags: java, prefix

```
int v=3;
int s=6 + (--v);

int d= --v + --v/s++*v++ + ++s%v--;
```

can someone which tell me how to go about this question??
in the end i m getting 9%0;

but the complier is showing the value of d as 1

can someone tell me where i made a mistake

Comment: The thing which confuses most people asking these sorts of questions is that evaluation order is always left-to-right; and that evaluation order is orthogonal to operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

For **Java**, as far as I can tell, the value of `d = 1` should be correct:

- EDIT: evaluation is order is from left to right (as Andy Turner stated in his comment)
- `++x` ⇒ increment first, then use variable
- `x++` ⇒ use first, then increment variable

So I get:

```
int v=3;
int s=6 + (--v); // s=8, v=2

int d = --v // 1
      + --v // 0
      / s++ // 8, s=9
      * v++ // 0, v=1
      + ++s // 10
      % v--; // 0
```

⇒ `d = 1 + 0 / 8 * 0 + 10 % 0`

According to operator precedence of `* / %` you get

```
d = 1 + 0 + 0
```

EDIT 2: Note that other languages might have other evaluation rules (as mentioned by @AdaRaider in the comments, also see my example for C++ there).

Comment: While I follow your logic here, when I run this code I get an exception; integer division by 0, therefore there must be something wrong with this understanding.

Comment: Just tested (copied code from question into Java class, added `System.out.println(d)` and run under Java 7u80) and result output was `1`.

Comment: Ah yes, programming language was not specified. Run it in C++

Comment: It had the `java` tag, so I assumed Java. ;)

Comment: I think it is still interesting to note that you get variable results in different languages, but good attention to detail and this does work in java. It might however be worth mentioning that in your answer in case someone thinks that this is true for all cases? The code snippet happens to look very language independent.

Comment: Main difference here seems to be that Java is specified to have an evaluation order from left to right (which results in `(0 / 8) * 0 = 0`). For C++ evaluation order is unspecified. The compiler can use any order as long as precedence rules are met. So it might come up with `0 / (8 * 0)` which would rise an error. That also means, if you'd use another C++ compiler the output may differ.

Comment: i still dont get why java did not giva a error when 10%0 came and how is its value 0